# Error: Function ISCHANGED may not be used in this type of formula

Tags: formula

I am implementing formula

```
AND(ISCHANGED(OwnerId),$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",RecordType.Name = "")
```

on formula field but every time this is giving me error .

> Error: Function ISCHANGED may not be used in this type of formula

People saying it will be applied on workflow rules , But I am not able to see where to apply formula in rules.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: There have got to be at least a half dozen duplicates here.

Answer (score 8):

You can only use ISCHANGED in the following cases:

> - Assignment rules
> - Validation rules
> - Field updates
> - Workflow rules if the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited .
> - Formula criteria for executing actions in the Process Builder.

This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US).

To use ISCHANGED in a Workflow Rule, use the "when the following formula evaluates to true" option.